# Sync postgres tables between two databases

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, data-synchronization

We have two Postgres database instances for two regions(Django application). These database instances have common and region-specific tables/data.  We have an admin panel, where an administrator modifies a few tables. Given that there are two regions, the administrator has to repeat the same activity in both the regions.
To overcome this, we have planned a "master" server where admin modifies the tables in the "master" server and the data must be replicated in both the region servers.

These tables have a "modified" timestamp, "last_synced" timestamp and a "reviewed" boolean and only rows marked reviewed and modified date >last_synced needs to be synced with the region servers. The sync process must also not sync certain columns in the table which are region specific. This need not be realtime and can be daily batch. As with any other database, the tables have a lot of foreign keys and all these must be replicated.

What would be the best option for this specific datasyc?

Comment: Could you work with a master DB that has these tables and the child sites just read that database for those tables/models? The syncing model you propose is complex and as such, prone to error

Comment: Valid point. However, we want the regions to be self-contained. e.g. we have a "visible" field which controls the data to be displayed to the user. One region may want to display the region and others may not want to display.